# Getting an error on my do while loop in the doAgain method

Tags: java

Getting an error on my do while loop in my `doAgain` method. Not sure why. Trying to use another Boolean method to check for mistakes in the user input :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            int digits = getDigits();
            System.out.println(createNumber(digits));
        } while (doAgain() != false);
    }

    public static int getDigits() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many digits do you want the num to be?");
        int digits = kb.nextInt();
        return digits;
    }

    public static String createNumber(int digits) {
        Random r = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(digits);
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
            sb.append((char) ('0' + r.nextInt(10)));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static boolean doAgain() {
        do {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String answer;
            System.out.println("Do you want to do this again? Enter yes to continue or no to quit");
            answer = kb.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("yes"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } while (incorrect(answer) != false);
    }

    public static boolean incorrect(String answer) {
        if (!answer.equals("yes") || !answer.equals("no"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on *getting an error*?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: At a glance, I would guess your `do...while` is irrelevant, as your returning true or false before checking the condition.

Comment: Can you try not to instanciate that many `Scanner` ? You should close them but in you case, you would close the `System.in` too ... breaking the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a some mistakes you made:

1. `!answer.equals("yes") || !answer.equals("no")` always returns `true`.
2. `answer` in `} while (incorrect(answer) != false);` is out of scope. You need to declare `String answer = "";` before the do-while loop.
3. The loop never repeats, because of you if else which always returns in the loop.

The fixed code can be:

```
public static boolean doAgain() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Do you want to do this again? Enter yes to continue or no to quit");
        answer = kb.nextLine();
    } while (incorrect(answer)); // Better not use double negative

    if (answer.equals("yes"))
        return true;
    else
       return false;
}

public static boolean incorrect(String answer) {
    if (answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"))
        return false; // answer is correct
    else
        return true; // answer is incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `String answer=""`; inside `doAgain` function. Otherwise you will get `cannot find symbol error` in this line

```
while (incorrect(answer) != false);
```

Modify doAgain function to this

```
 public static boolean doAgain() {
        String answer="";
        do {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
//            String answer;  // remove this 
            System.out.println("Do you want to do this again? Enter yes to continue or no to quit");
            answer = kb.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } while (incorrect(answer) != false);
    }
```

Comment: Use else if to check your false condition otherwise code will not go into while loop at all...